# Captcha library for Swing?

Tags: java, swing, captcha

I'm looking for a captcha library or component that I could use inside a Swing Gui. Do you know any ?

Edit: It seems not to exist. I'll program a small one myself.

Comment: why would you need one in the desktop application?

Comment: for registration in the remote users database

Comment: Capcha is used  to ensure that the response is generated by a person,  not a bot. How is this relevant to desktop applications? User/Password should be enough IMO

Comment: yes login/password is fine, but i would like to add a captcha at the moment of registration, to prevent bot registration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I don't really understand the need for captcha in Swing app, you can probably use JCaptcha http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 5):

Let me try to explain the reason @eugener tries to talk you out of a CAPTCHA: Normally a CAPTCHA is used to prevents bot registration as you already said. This is done by having the server post a problem, that the client/user has to solve. Since you are looking for a Swing lib it sounds like you want the client to pose the problem to the user.

In this case, you still need to transfer the result to the server and that request can still be forged by a bot. On the other hand, if you want the server to pose the problem for the CAPTCHA, you don't need a special lib on the client side. A simple `JLabel` to show the image with the problem and a `JTextField` for the answer will be enough.

> Sorry for not posting this in a
>   comment, but it has too many
>   characters...

Comment: That pretty much sums it up +1