# How to show a captcha in a java swing application

Tags: java, swing, captcha

I need to add a captcha validator in a java swing application. I have been searching some libraries (JCaptcha and SimpleCatcha) but they are for web development.

Is there any library to use captcha on swing? and if it's not, is there a web page or repository with some captcha caracters to implement my own captcha?

I really appreciate your time and your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question -- I did find this other similar question in which the answer talks about jCaptcha: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219029/captcha-library-for-swing -- Might I ask what the purpose for a captcha in a swing app is?

Comment: @ametren: if the Swing app is a front-end to a web application, I don't see why using CAPTCHAs would not be as useful as in the browser.

Comment: @JBNizet Ya, I can kind of see that, but it just seems to raise more questions for me -- like, for example, why would you front-end a web app with a swing app?  I'm not trying to talk the asker out of it, just trying to understand the use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm implementing a Login Window in java swing to log into my system. I Want the captcha to prevent multiconnections to my server system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JCaptcha can return a BufferedImage. From there it is not much difficult to get the image visible using a JLabel:

```
BufferedImage captcha = // Get the captcha
// See also com.octo.captcha.service.image.AbstractManageableImageCaptchaService.getImageChallengeForID(String)
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(captcha));
// ... add that label to a visible container of your Swing application
```

In version 1.0, you can use this: http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/apidocs/1.0/com/octo/captcha/service/image/AbstractManageableImageCaptchaService.html

In 2.0-alpha1, there is this: [http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/apidocs/2.0-alpha1/com/octo/captcha/service/image/AbstractManageableImageCaptchaService.html#getImageChallengeForID(java.lang.String)](http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/apidocs/2.0-alpha1/com/octo/captcha/service/image/AbstractManageableImageCaptchaService.html#getImageChallengeForID%28java.lang.String%29)

You can also check the overloaded version of those methods with an extra `Locale` argument.

In each case, there is a default implementing class `DefaultManageableImageCaptchaService`.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, I tried your answer and worked well,  I really really appreciate your help, only i had to change the way to put the captcha image in the label : BufferedImage imgCaptcha = servicioCaptcha.getImageChallengeForID(""+id);

Comment: Thanks!!! it works, so only to validate one mus use DefaultManageableImageCaptchaService::validateResponseForID(""+id, this.txtCaptcha.getText());  thanks i really appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

```
BufferedImage captcha = // Get the captcha

// See also 
com.octo.captcha.service.image.AbstractManageableImageCaptchaService.getImageChallengeForID(String)

JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(captcha));
// ... add that label to a visible container of your Swing application
```